# Adding css class to photos inside a dataframe

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

So I have a column in a dataframe which has two kinds of values: either an image or a text saying no image. What I want to do is to assign a css class (something like .photo) to all these photos, so I can then style the images using css. I tried doing this in R by adding

```
{.photo}
```

in front of every url link, but RMD file just renders the text as a string. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: How does a typical entry in the photo column look like? Is it a HTML link (`<img src="photo.jpg" />`) or is it just the name of the file? How are you then printing them in your document?